# How to just keep latest records in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

Here is my case,

```
Table name: EMP_Detail
Records:
ID          Name     Statue     ChangeDate
1111        Apple    Active     2017-01-01
1111        Apple    Active     2017-03-07
1111        Apple    Disabled   2017-04-06
1111        Apple    Active     2017-05-01
2222        Bell     Active     2017-02-05
2222        Bell     Active     2018-01-05
3333        Cisco    Active     2017-03-08
```

Trying to remove the active and out of date records and keep table like this:

```
ID          Name     Statue     ChangeDate
1111        Apple    Disabled   2017-04-06
1111        Apple    Active     2017-05-01
2222        Bell     Active     2018-01-05
3333        Cisco    Active     2017-03-08
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify two things: 1.If there are multiple `'Disabled'` rows with the same ID, do you want to keep only the latest or all of them? If there are 2 rows with same ID, an old one with Active and a newer with Disabled, should both be kept or only the newer (with Disabled)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and a CTE to delete from the source table.

```
;with cte as(
   select 
        *,
       RN = row_number() over (partition by [Name], [Status] order by [ChangeDate] desc, ID desc)
   from EMP_Detail)

delete from cte
where RN != 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to return your output.
The key points are :

```
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [Name], [Statue] ORDER BY [ChangeDate] DESC , ID DESC) AS RN
```

and

```
WHERE s.rn = 1
```

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_Detail
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(5), [Statue] varchar(8), [ChangeDate] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO EMP_Detail
    ([ID], [Name], [Statue], [ChangeDate])
VALUES
    (1111, 'Apple', 'Active', '2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (1111, 'Apple', 'Active', '2017-03-07 00:00:00'),
    (1111, 'Apple', 'Disabled', '2017-04-06 00:00:00'),
    (1111, 'Apple', 'Active', '2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
    (2222, 'Bell', 'Active', '2017-02-05 00:00:00'),
    (2222, 'Bell', 'Active', '2018-01-05 00:00:00'),
    (3333, 'Cisco', 'Active', '2017-03-08 00:00:00')
;

SELECT
  [ID], [Name], [Statue], [ChangeDate]
FROM
(
SELECT
  [ID], [Name], [Statue], [ChangeDate]
  ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [Name], [Statue] ORDER BY [ChangeDate] DESC , ID DESC) AS RN
FROM EMP_Detail
)S
WHERE s.rn = 1
ORDER BY [ID], [ChangeDate]
```

Output:

```
ID      Name    Statue      ChangeDate
1111    Apple   Disabled    06/04/2017
1111    Apple   Active      01/05/2017
2222    Bell    Active      05/01/2018
3333    Cisco   Active      08/03/2017
```

dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a2c5330c614b931bc3cc87f121e9b3a7)

update: to delete :

```
DELETE s
FROM
(
 SELECT
  [ID], [Name], [Statue], [ChangeDate]
  ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [Name], [Statue] ORDER BY [ChangeDate] DESC , ID DESC) AS RN
FROM EMP_Detail
)S
WHERE s.rn <> 1
```

Comment: Hi Sabin, Thank you for your help. I can get the result as you showed me. But I need to delete the unnecessary record from the original table. (Clean them out). How can I make it? Thanks,

Comment: @DBALUKEHUANG - to delete records, just add the query in the `from` clause of the delete statement - see update